# How do I create equation whose number matches my section number

Tags: equations, numbering

I am currently writing a paper in Latex. I am using \section, \subsection, etc. for sections. In each section I use

```
\begin{equation}
bla...
\end{equation}
```

for equations I have.

I want my equation to be numbered like (3.3.1), (3.3.2), ... for section (3.3) and so on, but the code I used just gave me equations numbered (1), (2), .... I am wondering how to change the way I number my equations.

Comment: Did you try `\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}`?

Comment: @Eddy_Em That's exactly what I want, thanks.